# Character String Indexing Issue

Tags: c++, string, indexing

When i print out the values of the character string "name" with absolute index values i get the right prinout. However when i use the variable "X" i get random data even though X appears to have the right values of O and 1 from their printout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char name[1];

    cout << "Type aa ab ba or bb" << endl;

    fgets(name, 3, stdin);

    cout << "The first letter of the name is " << name[0] << endl;
    cout << "The second letter of the name is " << name[1] << endl;

    int name_length;

    name_length = strlen(name);

    cout << "The length of the name is " << name_length << endl;

    char Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][1];

    /* Set the Main Chaldean Kaballah */

    Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[0][0] = 'A';
    Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][0] = 'B';

    Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][0] = 1;
    Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][1] = 2;

    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int Chaldean_Letter_Counter = 0;

    cout << "Name_Length is " << name_length << "  Chaldean_Letter_Counter "
            << Chaldean_Letter_Counter << endl;

    for (x = 0; x <= name_length - 1; x = x + 1)
    {

        cout << "x " << x << " Name Length is " << name_length << endl;

        for (Chaldean_Letter_Counter = 0; Chaldean_Letter_Counter <= 1;
                Chaldean_Letter_Counter = Chaldean_Letter_Counter + 1)
        {

            cout << "Chaldean Letter Counter" << Chaldean_Letter_Counter << endl;
            cout << "x " << x << " Name letter " << name[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've declared `name` as containing 1 `char` (`name[1\]`), so the only valid index into it is `name[0]`. (Actually, a 1 element array of `char` isn't an array; it's a `char`, and you could declare it as `char name` instead.) If you want it to hold 2 characters, declare it with the appropriate size.

Comment: Ken is correct.  And, I'd change to `fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin)` to prevent a segfault/bad corruption instead of merely incorrect results